# What is the best way to offer people to install a script plus simple dependencies

Tags: shell-script, software-installation

I have a trivial project which consists of a simple executable script plus a couple of data files.

I'd want to offer a way for users to install this; which would just consist of copying the script to `/usr/local/bin/` and the data files to `/usr/local/share` I guess.
Of course I can provide a `Makefile` for this but this would introduce a requirement on `make`. Should I just supply a simple shell script instead for this task?

Also, if possible I would want to make it easy for distro packagers (Fedora, Debian, etc) to create a package. I guess they will not use my install script anyway, would they? Is there any info on how to approach this? The Linux distributions only have info on 'how to package for x' but not 'how to create a software so we can easily package it for x' or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of making your script easy to install could be to allow it to install itself (with a suitable option)... It’s perhaps unorthodox but it should suit your purposes reasonably well, at least for end users. Do make sure you use a sub-directory of `/usr/local/share`, not `/usr/local/share` directly. You might also want to consider allowing installation in a user’s home directory — if your script can work with its data alongside it, that would be the simplest option.

For packagers, you’re right that a simple package would probably not rely on an installation mechanism you provide: it’s just as easy to tell the packaging system to copy three files to the appropriate place. For packages, you’ll have to ensure that your script can easily handle being installed in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/share/<something>` instead of `/usr/local/...`.

See [Debian’s upstream guide](https://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide) for a comprehensive guide describing how to be a package-friendly upstream developer. Most of the recommendations in the guide aren’t Debian-specific. (Most also won’t apply to you in this particular case!)